# Finding the perimeter of a parallelogram.

Tags: geometry

ABCD is a parallellogram in which $$\angle D  = 120^\circ .$$

The bisector of angle D bisects the side AB.
If the length of the bisector is 5 cm, then what is the perimeter of the parallelogram.

Can this be solved using the `sin` rule or `cosine` rule?

How i can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $A$ be to top left vertex, $B$ the top right, $C$ the bottom right and $D$ the bottom left.  Let $E$ be the point of intersection of the angle bisector with $AB$.

Draw a picture and note that $DE$, $AE$, and $DA$  are the sides of an equilateral triangle. Each side of this triangle has length 5. From this you can find the perimeter of $ABCD$.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's denote perimeter as $p$ and length of bisector as $x$ (see picture below) , then :

$p=2\cdot(2x+x)=6 \cdot x=30$ cm

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$30$, because $\angle A=120^\circ$ we have $\angle B=\angle C= \frac{360^\circ-2\cdot 120^\circ}{2}=60^\circ$. Therefore $BDS$ is a eqilateral triangle, so $\overline{BD}=\overline{SD}=5\text{cm}$ ($S$ is the point, where the bisector hits $\overline{AB}$).

Then you have $\overline{AB}=2\overline{BS}=2\overline{BD}=10\text{cm}$.

Summing it up, you get $\overline{AB}+\overline{BD}+\overline{DC}+\overline{AC}=10\text{cm}+5\text{cm}+10\text{cm}+5\text{cm}=30\text{cm}$.